# multiple ffmpeg library paths, how can exclude older ffmpeg installations?

Tags: linux, compiling, libraries

I am trying to compile [Simple Screen Recorder](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr). I had a linker error due to a wrong library path relating to `ffmpeg`.

When I checked installation paths with `whereis ffmpeg`, I get:

```
ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/X11/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg
```

I installed `ffmpeg` many times, without uninstalling old one, now I face a linker error.

How can I exclude older `ffmpeg` installations and fix the library path problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables. make sure they are point to correct version of ffmpeg and does not include older version

if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not already setup then try this :

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ffmpeg`